# Php Methode Prototypage Heritage

Tags: php, object, inheritance, prototype, extends

I take again an old dev on php.
When I was young, I loved Object and heritage, and I was able to do :

```
abstract class ABSObject {
 static protected function save(ABSObject $obj=NULL) {
  ...
 }
}

class EXTObject extends ABSObject {
 static protected function save(EXTObject $obj=NULL) {
  ...
 }
}
```

it's was fine in the begin of php5 (2012 years code).
but now in php 5.6 and tested in php 7.
We have only this good know well message :

```
Warning: Declaration of EXTObject::save(EXTObject $obj = NULL) should be compatible with ABSObject::save(ABSObject $obj = NULL)
```

Yes, really, I can change for :

```
class EXTObject extends ABSObject {
 static protected function save(ABSObject $obj=NULL) {
  ...
 }
}
```

and that is work well, but i was alone for find that pratical and usefull?

Comment: Were you alone in using doing that? No. Is it practical and useful, well I'd say no. Personally I'd call that a code smell and a work around for better practice for the sake of time / effort (or not knowing better).

Comment: If you declare that all your methods must implement a particular signature, then they must implement the signature you declare. Otherwise it's pretty useless to declare a particular signature in the first place if children don't stick to them anyway. The chance to introduce actual incompatibilities with this on `static` methods is arguably lower than on instance methods, but still existent. This is explained in-depth in the duplicate.

Comment: I agree about duplicate question, I wasn't found before thanks a lot.
Yes, I understand now, about SOLID rule and Liskov substitution principle, I learn every day, thanks to every one who had help me.
Your answer are really smart, congratulation.

Comment: Sorry to come back on. 
But normally, when EXTObject->save is call with an EXTObject param, it's should be call the EXTObject->save and when EXTObject->save is call with an ABSObject or an other object who inherit ABSObject it's should call ABSObject->save.

it's like methode surchage for me, like a basic, you can make :
 function save ( int param ); 
 function save ( string param );
and the good methode is called if param is int or string.
No?